# how can I add styles of structure to jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I just wrote a jquery plugin that makes operations on a table (like grid plugin).

The plugin add some styles like `overflow:hidden;` to cells and borders to the table and the cells (in order to keep on uniform border width I added: `.MyTable {border-width:0 0 1px 1px;}` and `.MyTable > tr > td {border-width:1px 1px 0 0 }`.

Now I am wonder how and where to put this css styles.
I can put them on external css file but then I force the user to add .css file to her page. In order to make the plugin accessable to all users, even the new ones, this could be an obstacle. A user might forget to add the css file or even change it's content in order to achieve something and this will make the plugin work unproperly.
In addition, I want to let the user the ability to change things (like the border's width). In case I put the css on external file, the user can change anything she desires by herself.

Another option, I can also assign the styles directly on the jquery elem (using elem.css(...) command). Thats way the user don't have to deal with css file in order to work properly and in the other way in order to allow changes in styles (like the border) I can add an option to the plugin. But, this way I creating unefficient code and I merge between behaviour and design.

Is there any other possibility to add styles to jquery plugins?
What is the best way to do it?

I am NOT talking about a style that should determine color or font, but styles that are necessary to the structure I make!

Comment: `$('<style type="text/css">#selectors {/*styles*/}</style>').appendTo('head');`, or: `$('<style type="text/css">').text('#selectors {/*Styles*/}').appendTo('head');`.

Comment: @Rob W: But then if this plugin executed twice, those styles loaded again..

Comment: This is the point where common sense comes in ;) Attach a very unique ID to your `<style>` tag, then check for the existence of this ID prior inserting the style sheet.

Comment: @Rob W: You mean to give id to the <style> tag?

Comment: `if(!$('#rw-jq-plugin-stylesheet').length){$('<style type="text/css" id="rw-jq-plugin-stylesheet">#selectors {/*styles*/}</style>').appendTo('head');}`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically add a `<style>` element to the page.  Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vpPpT/

```
$('<style>body { background-color: red; color: white; }</style>').appendTo('head');
```

The above example is just [one of many ways](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) you can create DOM elements on-the-fly.

Also, here's someone that was trying to do something similar (although for all the wrong reasons):

- [jQuery Creating a style element on fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224192/jquery-creating-a-style-element-on-fly)

Comment: I saw this method. Such way could cause the style added to the head multiple times. If the plugin executed twice, those styles added again to the head.

Comment: Why is the method you presented is the best method?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can (should) give your `<style>` tag an `id` attribute with your plugin's namespace. Then check for the existence of this `id` before appending the `<style>` element.

Comment: It's the best because it avoids the need of an external stylesheet and it's reusable CSS (unlike using inline CSS, including jQuery's `.css()` function)